# Doctrine2 ORM OneToMany or ManyToOne not working

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I would like to have the relationship between 2 tables, with OneToMany and ManyToOne relationships.

```
Survey
id
title

Questions:
id 
survey_id
```

So i am looking to list the surveys and their respective questions,  so how can i achieve that.

Here is my code,

**Survey Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Survey\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;


/**
 * Description of Survey
 *
 * @author Mubarak
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="surveys")
 */

class Survey extends BaseEntity{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->questions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Survey\Entity\Questions", mappedBy="surveys")
     */
    private $questions;

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuestions() {
        return $this->questions;
    }

    public function setQuestions(ArrayCollection $questions) {
        $this->questions = $questions;
    }


    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [id: {$this->id}, name: {$this->name}]";
    }
}
```

**Below is the Questions Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Survey\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;


/**
 * Description of Survey Questions
 *
 * @author Mubarak
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="survey_questions")
 */

class Questions extends BaseEntity{



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Survey\Entity\Survey", inversedBy="questions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="survey_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $surveys;

    public function getQuestion() {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion($question) {
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getSurveys() {
        return $this->surveys;
    }

    public function setSurveys(ArrayCollection $surveys) {
        $this->surveys = $surveys;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [id: {$this->id}, name: {$this->name}]";
    }
}
```

What is the mistake i am doing here, this is my code to get the surveys and questions:

```
$surveysInterface = $this->surveyService->getAllSurveys();
            foreach($surveysInterface as $survey){
                $surveysArray[] = array(
                    'id' => $survey->getId(),
                    'title' => $survey->getTitle(),
                    'description' => $survey->getDescription(),
                    'isActive' => $survey->getActive(),
                    'questions' => array(
                        'question' => $survey->getQuestions()->getQuestion()
                    )
                );
            }
```

Comment: 'questions' => array( 'question' => $survey->getQuestions()->getQuestion()) looks wrong. change it to 'questions' => $survey->getQuestions() . What output do you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'questions' => array(
                    'question' => $survey->getQuestions()->getQuestion()
                    )
```

This part look wrong since getQuestions() function return array of **Questions** entities. Suggest to change it to

```
'questions' => $survey->getQuestions()
```